# (Newbie Processing Q) How do you slow down the the fading of colors? And how do you stop a moving object?

Tags: processing

I'm a newbie who working on processing code. I'm using a variable to fade light blue into a darker blue and that's working fine, but I was wondering how I could slow the process of it fading.

Another question(hope people don't mind me asking two on one post), is how do I make a shape stop moving at a certain point? I have a ellipse there labelled the sun. I'd like it to stop when x=700.

Here's my coding:

```java
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float r = 0;
int gb = 0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(gb, gb, 255);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  background(0, gb, 255);
  gb++;

  if (gb>50) {
    //the sun
    fill(243, 230, 0);
    ellipse(x, 60, 75, 75);
    fill(243, 230, 0, 80);
    ellipse(x, 60, 90, 90);
    x++;
  }

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(0, 380, 800, 450);
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering how I could slow the process of it fading.

Check out this line:

```
gb++;
```

Here you're incrementing (adding 1 to) your `gb` variable, which you're using to determine the color. To slow down the color changing, just add a smaller value to it. Something like this:

```
gb = gb + .1;
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
gb += .1;
```

For this to work, you'll have to change your `gb` variable to be a `float` so it can hold decimals.

You might also want to check out the `lerp()` and `map()` functions in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

> Another question(hope people don't mind me asking two on one post), is how do I make a shape stop moving at a certain point? I have a ellipse there labelled the sun. I'd like it to stop when x=700.

In the future, please only ask one question per post. And try to put together a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each question instead of posting your whole sketch.

But you can do this with an `if` statement that only increments `x` when it is less than `700`. Like this:

```
if(x < 700){
  x++;
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on using `if` statements to create animations in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).